# 90’s-00’s fantasy book about fae/elf who have to breed with goblins to produce fae/elf children

Tags: story-identification, books, elves, fairy

I read a book, probably late 90’s where a fae or elf girl’s mother had died. She was arranged a marriage, and set up an estate with her husband. But all their children were demi-fae, brownies etc. She thought she finally had a full fae/elf daughter who didn’t change, but after many years the girl suddenly became a siren, creating a huge lake or sea. She somehow discovered the problem is she has to travel to Earth and breed with a descendant of a goblin. The goblins are some kind of warrior army security culture. She does this, and somehow there is a threat from Earth. Someone comes over with a news van? Satellite? Her siren daughter and other demi children help fend off the humans.